# Conflict easyXDM with MooTools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

MooTools wrapped all methods and when easyXDM (http://easyxdm.net/wp/) convert JSON to string (stringify) methods of MooTools get there.
How can I remove Mootools wrapping?

Comment: can you show your codes, that how you implement easyXDM?? means with jquery or javascript??

Comment: When I try to send message occurs error: throw new SyntaxError("JSON.parse") (json2.min.js)

Comment: In firebug I saw when called method stringify (in JSON) obj paramater contains function of MooTools and because of them, the JSON parser breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please be more specific. provide an example, if you can, what breaks, what do you call etc.

For the record, MooTools will NOT take over the native JSON methods. It will export `JSON.encode` and `JSON.decode` on the JSON host object - based on `.stringify` / `.parse`, if available - or it will add its own fallbacks if not.

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Utilities/JSON.js#L46-79

XDM will check if JSON is available here:

https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM/blob/master/src/Core.js#L415

When mootools is already running `JSON` will be defined but `JSON.stringify` may not be so it should do its thing.

MooTools does not provide `Object.toJSON` either so the other possible way it may fail to work is not that: https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Types/Object.js

So, unless you can demonstrate what fails, we can't help you. One thing you can do is, build your own version of MooTools and take out JSON, if you don't want it.

http://mootools.net/core/ - just tick what you really need from it.

Comment: also, what can easyXDM do that you cannot already do through mootools and the Request / Request.JSONP stacks with CORS?